# Smarty, include css/javascript file

Tags: php, templates, include, smarty, assign

is it real to include differents CSS or JavaScript files, on the page, depending on its name.
For example if i have page orders, will be included `orders.css`, and if i have index page  will be included `index.css`, or maybe with others checks, if x = 3 include `main.js`, if x = 5 include `validate.js`.

I understand that i can do this by PHP, something like:

```
if (x = 3) $smarty->assign('file_css', 'orders');
else $smarty->assign('file_css', 'index');
```

and in template write something like:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/{$file_css}.css' />
```

But maybe there is a way to do this by smarty ?

Some time ago, i saw in project something like blocks in smarty template, where was css/js files, and they included to page by some magic, mby by PHP i dont know, but its looks very clear, and comfortably. There was 1 file, where was something like:

```
{smarty block='css'}
    <link ....... />
    <script ..... />
{/smarty block}
```

And then this blocks was included in necessary places on template.

It's just example, i don't remember how it really called, but it was something like this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use {smarty.template} which gives current template name with .tpl extension like "orders.tpl".
Replace extension with your option

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/{$smarty.template|replace :'.tpl':'.css'}' />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can go about doing what you want. However, you're probably thinking about template inheritance.

You can probably do something like this example and in main.tpl append the CSS with a different style sheet.

> index.tpl

```
<html> 
<head> 
{block name='head'}{/block} 
</head> 
<body> 
{block name='body_main'}{block} 
</body> 
</html>
```

> main.tpl

```
{block name='head' append} 
<--  your css  --> 
{/block} 
{block name='body_main'} 
your content here 
{/block}
```

Take a look here for more info. 
http://www.smarty.net/inheritance

Comment: Thank you very much, its a really cool way to do it. Better than if, else :)